# Submitting tasks to background threads Python Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I am using `Flask` for my simple REST API.

What I need to implement is async execution. Here is the flow

`Request --> Immediate Response --> Submitting background job with a callback --> Execution of the background job --> Calling the callback`

I am newbie to Python, there are lot of ways like `asyncio`, `thread pools` and others. I am not sure which one suits better for me.

Also I this job will be run periodically by timer, so I guess `Thread Pool` is the right choice, but not sure.

Could you please suggest the best way to follow in my case.

I would be grateful for any examples or suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Currently, I think your question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow.  You're unlikely to get a good answer until you have specific questions about a framework or some code. Unless you have some unusual requirements, I recommend just picking any library with a good tutorial and go from there.

Comment: As the previous comment mentio, I agree that your question is too broad, nevertheless have a look to http://www.celeryproject.org/. It is a well established and documented queue library which main purpose is asynchronous tasks.